# DataStoreAdapterException in IBM WAS connect to SQL server DB

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I am not able to connect the Sql server db from IBM WAS6. It throws below exception, I already added sqljdbc4.jar in classpath.

com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.exceptions.DataStoreAdapterException: DSRA8050W: Unable to find the DataStoreHelper class specified: com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.MicrosoftSQLServerDataStoreHelper

Not sure is it requires any new JAR file? Can you please help me to solve the issue.